# correct syntax for SQL calls in python with pyodbc

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pyodbc

I need help to write the SQL calls from my python scripts in a proper way.
what I my script currently looks like is :

```
import pyodbc
cnx = pyodbc.connect(**connection details**)
c = cnx.cursor()
results = c.execute("select * .....")
final_result= results.fetchall()
```

issue is sometimes result value is **NONE** type object and sometimes I get a return values.

I want to know if the below way is a correct way to call  , because it seems to work everytime for all the queries

```
import pyodbc

cnx = pyodbc.connect(**connection details**)

c = cnx.cursor()

c.execute("select * .....")
final_result= c.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach is correct and is what many DB API modules require. However, pyodbc has extended the DB API specification so that `Cursor.execute()` [returns the Cursor object itself](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Features-beyond-the-DB-API#cursorexecute-returns-the-cursor) so you can simply do

```py
final_result = c.execute("select * .....").fetchall()
```

Comment: I did try with
 """ final_result = c.execute("select * .....").fetchall() """. But it was returning a None object.

Comment: What version of pyodbc are you using?

Comment: i am using version 4.0.30

Comment: The actual scenario is I have been provided a Stored Procedure by a client that should return me contents when I call it, when I execute the procedure in SQL CLI/studio it returns me appropriate results, but when I call it via pyodbc it returns nothing

Comment: I see you've opened a new question regarding the stored procedure call. Thanks for doing that.